# How to open specific apps and arrange them to different desktops automatically?

Tags: macos, applescript, desktop, automation

I'm using my MacBook doing quite different things from time to time. For example, at home, I may want to open `file1.xlsx`, `file2.xlsx` with Excel on Desktop 2, while Chrome opened with tags of Google, Youtube on Desktop 1. While at work, I need to open `code-folder1/` and `code-folder2/` with Visual Studio Code on Desktop 2, and StackOverflow and Github with Chrome on Desktop 1. (In real world, I can spend 3 to 5 minutes to setup a working status).

Is there any tool, or scripts I can use to automatically close redundant applications, open specific tabs or files with desired ones, and arrange them in usual place?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I see you've added the GeekTool tag to your question. Is that because you're specifically after a solution that involves using GeekTool, or...?

Comment: @Monomeeth Thanks for responding. There's no description for tag `geektool`, I thought it means general geek tools. This tag has been removed.

Comment: Not specifically what you are looking for, but rectangle has helped me a lot organizing my desktops and is free